# How can I pass the entire ListView item from one Activity to another in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, listview

I want to pass the entire ListView item from one Activity to another.
My code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It would be better If you pass arraylist instead of passing listview then set arraylist to second activiy listview.

Comment: first why you need to pass view to other activity? secondly why you not pass list to other activity?

Comment: Simply pass your object position and get it in next activiyt using serializable and extend your modal class with serializable or post your listActivity code and modal code also

Answer (score 0):

Well you should get the list (ArrayList not the ListView) from the adapter and give it to the current activity. From there you should put it in the Intent you are using to start the second activity. Then get it from the second activity's intent and pass it to the adapter of the second activty.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, just send the list from firstActivity to secondActivity.

**FirstActivity**

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
intent.putExtra("mylist", myList);
```

In secondActivity recieve the list and set it to listView or send it to your customAdatper class If you have made CustomListView. Make sure you have also declear ListView in your secondActivity.

**SecondActivity**

```
ArrayList<String> myList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("mylist");
```